# ¿How can I edit the main theme of my Wordpress theme with King Composer?

Tags: wordpress, edit

I'm trying to customize a theme that I bought for WordPress.
My knowledge in PHP is null, because I use King Composer as the editor that comes with the subject.
I am starting to modify parts of the theme, but the main cover, which I show in the capture, I can not change the background image of the beginning of my site.
They are two different images that alternate, and the text that each one has.
I leave the link to my site, I guess I offer them a lot so they can help me, but looking for the files I do not know how to edit, so I use King Composer.
I've seen tutórales, but they focused on blog and I did not find a way to solve this, like changing the images of the slider.
Sorry to offer you just this, if you give me more ideas so you can help me.
Thank you.

http://howello.bolvo.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your slider is controlled by a plugin called Revolution slider.

You should see an option for this in the wordpress admin menu on the main side bar to the left. You can change the image by finding the correct slide (as  i presume there will be multiple) and editing it.

You can find the documentation here: https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/slider-revolution-documentation/

Comment: Thanks @AshleyBrown,  But I can not find the way to edit the image, when I give> customize> the option does not appear with the images ....

Comment: I already discovered how to edit thanks to your link, thanks.